# Unable to authenticate in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I am using PostgreSQL 9.3 in an Ubuntu 14.04 and I always use this procedure to access psql:

```
sudo -i -u postgres
psql
```

Until now it returns this:

```
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
password retrieved from file "/var/lib/postgresql/.pgpass"
```

The content of **/var/lib/postgresql/.pgpass** is:

```
*:*:*:postgres:Vdjui6OTF6ab3Jzf77dVeOa88t7OdK
*:*:*:vmail:pxrw23PsaJOBDfZxIcImhAkzUzH4cA
*:*:*:vmailadmin:6XLhFMc5KWYpdXGE7TCfCHZSDkqzXJ
*:*:*:iredapd:5D6Yl2iRu56Dma2uRXDGSAP89JQQHE
*:*:*:iredadmin:xklX0IgJOQVGklDNFlLckPznq5L7ZG
*:*:*:sogo:PZdclHCua2Ip10yddVw4odSjr0dfZk
*:*:*:roundcube:kByuTSkilZWglYzv24unwfenUZkR7u
*:*:*:amavisd:UEBpiDEvsIbogEB5stJl1YP8DvMCWZ
```

Comment: Try to drop the -i "sudo -u postgres psql" should work on a vanilla install

Comment: Does the first line in pg_hba.conf look like this? "local   all         postgres"

Comment: Solved it by the way

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! I entered this in the terminal instead:

```
psql -U postgres
```

Then input my password